# ngx bootstrap typeahead validation based on the values list

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngx-bootstrap

The application is using Angular 2 and Bootstrap 3. User needs to be provided with a long length list of values to select from. I came to ngx-bootstrap Typehead component (http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead). How the typed value could be validated against the list. With default configuration user can type any value in the input and leave the control without selecting anything form the list. I want to force user to select from the list just like normal drop-downs just with extra ability to filter values by typing.

Comment: I think you might need to add more information. Do you have code or a plunker that we could see?

Comment: No plunker, I am looking for the available options. I have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881815/implementing-autocomplete-for-angular2/35908611 but there are some issue around that as well. I am going to try it.

Comment: Not specific to ngx-bootstrap, but the type-ahead filter is returning an array of the filtered values. You can check against this array based on the input. If the length of the array == 1 you know the input is valid. Otherwise it is invalid.